# Load multiple Json zip file from GCS to BigQuery using Dataflow pipeline (python)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am completely new to Dataflow and naïve programmer. I am looking for help in designing a dataflow pipeline written in python to read multi parted compressed Json files stored on GCS to load to BigQuery.
The source couldn't provide us with the Schema of the file/table. So, I am looking for an autodetect option. something like below:

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
)
```

I don't require any transformations. Just wanted to load json to BQ.

I couldn't find any sample template on google that reads a json.zip file with auto detect and writes to BQ. Can someone help me with a template or syntax for above requirement or tips and points that I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Beam Python's [fileio](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html) transforms have what you need to read zipped JSON. You can specify a compression type and file suffix. The tutorial on [File Processing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/) will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Python Beam executable code and sample raw data.

```
#------------Import Lib-----------------------#
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import window
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import os, sys, time
import argparse
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from datetime import datetime

#------------Set up BQ parameters-----------------------#
# Replace with Project Id
project = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
input='gs://FILE-Path'
#plitting Of Records----------------------#

class Transaction_ECOM(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)

        result = json.loads(element)
        data_bkt = result.get('_bkt','null')
        data_cd=result.get('_cd','null')
        data_indextime=result.get('_indextime','0')
        data_kv=result.get('_kv','null')
        data_raw=result['_raw']
        data_raw1=data_raw.replace("\n", "")
        data_serial=result.get('_serial','null')
        data_si = str(result.get('_si','null'))
        data_sourcetype =result.get('_sourcetype','null')
        data_subsecond = result.get('_subsecond','null')
        data_time=result.get('_time','null')
        data_host=result.get('host','null')
        data_index=result.get('index','null')
        data_linecount=result.get('linecount','null')
        data_source=result.get('source','null')
        data_sourcetype1=result.get('sourcetype','null')
        data_splunk_server=result.get('splunk_server','null')

        return [{"datetime_indextime": time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(data_indextime))), "_bkt": data_bkt, "_cd": data_cd,  "_indextime": data_indextime,  "_kv": data_kv,  "_raw": data_raw1,  "_serial": data_serial,  "_si": data_si, "_sourcetype": data_sourcetype, "_subsecond": data_subsecond, "_time": data_time, "host": data_host, "index": data_index, "linecount": data_linecount, "source": data_source, "sourcetype": data_sourcetype1, "splunk_server": data_splunk_server}]



def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)


    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)



    data_loading = (
        p1
        |'Read from File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input,skip_header_lines=0)


    )


    project_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    dataset_id = 'test123'
    table_schema_ECOM = ('datetime_indextime:DATETIME, _bkt:STRING, _cd:STRING, _indextime:STRING, _kv:STRING, _raw:STRING, _serial:STRING, _si:STRING, _sourcetype:STRING, _subsecond:STRING, _time:STRING, host:STRING, index:STRING, linecount:STRING, source:STRING, sourcetype:STRING, splunk_server:STRING')

        # Persist to BigQuery
        # WriteToBigQuery accepts the data as list of JSON objects

#---------------------Index = ITF----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    result = (
    data_loading
        | 'Clean-ITF' >> beam.ParDo(Transaction_ECOM())
        | 'Write-ITF' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table='CFF_ABC',
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project_id,
                                                    schema=table_schema_ECOM,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                                                    ))

    result = p1.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  path_service_account = '/home/vibhg/Splunk/CFF/xxxxxxxxxxx-abcder125.json'
  os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account
  run()
```

It has few additional libraries so just ignore it.

Sample data which can be stored on GCS, that is given below:-

```
{"_bkt": "A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787687", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:59,126 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\", Locality=\"NA\", Success=\"True\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:00.005\", OrderNo=\"374941817\", Locality=\"NA\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\"], [userId=\"s-oitp-u-global\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccc\"], [msgIdSeq=\"2\"], [originator=\"ISOM\"] ", "_serial": "0", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".126", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:59.126 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
{"_bkt": "itf~412~2EE5428B-7CEA-4C49-A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787687", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:59,126 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\", Locality=\"NA\", Success=\"True\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:00.005\", OrderNo=\"374941817\", Locality=\"NA\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\"], [userId=\"s-oitp-u-global\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccc\"], [msgIdSeq=\"2\"], [originator=\"ISOM\"] ", "_serial": "0", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".126", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:59.126 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
{"_bkt": "9-A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787671", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:58,659 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsCreateOrderV2\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:01.568\", OrderNo=\"374942155\", CountryCode=\"US\", ClientSystem=\"owfe-webapp\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsCreateOrderV2\"], [userId=\"s-salja1-u-irssemal\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"6652311fece28966\"], [msgIdSeq=\"25\"], [originator=\"SellingApi\"] ", "_serial": "1", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".659", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:58.659 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
```

You can execute script with following command :-

```
python script.py --region europe-west1 --project xxxxxxx --temp_location gs://temp/temp --runner DataflowRunner --job_name name
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code Vibhor. Since I am completely new, I do have few questions. It would be great if you could help me with this. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. In the Process method, you did split the file and when returning, you have added 2 time columns to the existing columns. Do I have any option to auto detect the schema? And you haven't specified about the file compression. I need to read multiple json Zip files.How to handle repeat records? could you plz explain the last 4 lines of the code . Once again thank you so much for the help. Looking forward .