# How to store and serve coupons with Google tools and javascript

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-tag-manager

I'll get a list of coupons by mail. That needs to be stored somewhere somehow (bigquery?) where I can request and send it to the user. The user should only be able to get 1 unique code, that was not used beforehand.

I need the ability to get a code and write, that it was used, so the next request gets the next code...

I know it is a completely vague question but I'm not sure how to implement that, anyone has any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thr can be multiples solution for same requirement, one of them is given below :-

Step 1. Try to get `coupons` over a file (CSV, JSON, and etc) as per your preference/requirement.

Step 2. Load Source file to GCS (storage).

Step 3. Write a Dataflow code which read data from GCS (file) an load data to a different Bigquery table (tentative name: **New_data**). [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230258/load-multiple-json-zip-file-from-gcs-to-bigquery-using-dataflow-pipeline-python/66232853#66232853).

Step 4. Create a Dataflow code to read data from Bigquery table **New_data** and compare it with **History_data** and identify new `coupons` and write data to a file on GCS or Bigquery table. [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789).

Step 5. Schedule entire process over an orchestrator/Cloud scheduler/Cron tab job.

Step 6. Once you have data you can send it to consumers through any communication channel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I don't know how to do what you propose but I'll find out! With your response, I have at least a guide and a start point! Thank you for sharing your knowledge @Vibhor Gupta

Comment: Great to hear that. All the best!!